# Как искать unicode chars с xpath

Tags: php, xpath

Здравствуйте, подскажите почему xpath не чего не находит в документе, хотя через chrome все гуд.

```
//*[contains(text(), "✈")]/ancestor::div[1]
```

в документе ✈ хранится в виде иконки.

Comment: приведите пример xml с такими символами

Comment: В общим с кодировкой дока проблема была